# Laravel 5.4 Auth::attempt works, Cannot pass auth middleware

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm having some trouble with laravel 5.4 authentication.
Out of the box the auth worked although I couldn't access Auth::user().
After some changes that had to be made for FrontEnd considerations, I added a new login function that uses Auth::attempt($credentials) like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Models;
use Auth;
use Log;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home-page';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function login(){
    if(Auth::guest()){
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')])) {
            Log::debug(Auth::user());
            return redirect('/home-page');
        }
    }

    return 'cannot log in';
}

}
```

The login passes, the redirect works, and Auth::user() is accessible.

The problem is that after the redirect ,all routes guarded by 'auth' middleware are not accessible.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('some-route', function(){
        return view('some-view');
    }
});
```

Moreover, I tried to see if I can access the user there but Auth::user() returns null.

Notes: 
1. User table is the one that was created by the Laravel user table migration.
2. Registering users via RegisterController (got from php artisan make:auth)
3. Only change in auth.php is this:

```
'providers' => [
'users' => [
   'driver' => 'eloquent',
   'model' => App\Models\User::class,
],
],
```

Would love to hear new suggestions, I can't figure what's wrong here.

Comment: Are you using api.php ?

Comment: Yeah, the login route is under api. just moved it to web to see if that helps, no luck

Comment: Yes it only work in `web.php` as `api.php` is stateless not `Auth` class will work in `api.php`